# does aws athena have the equivalent of select struct('*') in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, presto, amazon-athena, trino

related doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/rows-and-structs.html

spark hast the struct('*') function that converts a row to a nested struct:
for example:
if t has the columns a and b

```
t.select(struct('*').alias('x')
```

will have a column x which is a struct with a and b fields

what I found in athena requires explicitly specifying all fields:

```
select cast(row(a,b) as row(a varchar, b varchar)) as x from t
```

this is fine for a small number of columns, but is hard to work with for tables with a large number of rows

is there a way to create a nested row in athena that doesn't requires explicitly specifying all fields?

Comment: I always thought explicit was better than implicit. Code stays more readable, and easily debug-able and so on. `select * ` in many cases is not the best practice.

Comment: You can use generic ARRAY or MAP, or specify your expectation:

`SELECT CAST(JSON '{"k1":1,"k2":23,"k3":456}' AS MAP(VARCHAR, INTEGER)); -- {k1=1, k2=23, k3=456}

SELECT CAST(JSON '{"v1":123,"v2":"abc","v3":true}' AS ROW(v1 BIGINT, v2 VARCHAR, v3 BOOLEAN)); -- {v1=123, v2=abc, v3=true}

SELECT CAST(JSON '[123,"abc",true]' AS ROW(v1 BIGINT, v2 VARCHAR, v3 BOOLEAN)); -- {value1=123, value2=abc, value3=true}`